# Parallelizing Loops: Where is the unsafe dependence?

Tags: multithreading, dependencies, solaris

I'm trying to parallelize the following loop using the automatic parallelization options present in the Solaris Studio Complier.

```
int max = A->m;
complex** A_me2;    
complex fred;   

for ( i = 0; i < max; i++ )
{
    for ( j = 0; j < i-1; j++ )
    {
        A_me2[i][j] = fred;
        A_me2[i][j] = fred;
    }
}
```

However when I run this loop through the compiler I get a message saying: "not parallelized, unsafe dependence". Where exactly is the unsafe dependence? There is clearly no aliasing between the inputs and outputs of both assignment statements, and i and j are private to each thread... I'm extremely stumped as to why this is happening. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since `A_me2` is an array of pointers, the compiler doesn't know (for example) that `A_me2[0]` and `A_me2[1]` don't overlap, leading to multiple writes to the same location that need to be ordered correctly.  There is often a compiler `#pragma` that will tell the compiler to assume that there are no dependencies, overriding the automatic safety mechanisms.

Comment: I'm not sure about pragmas but isn't the restrict keyword used to let the complier know the pointers do not overlap? Also if what you say is correct then why does the following code parallelize as expected?

Comment: @FreaknBigPanda: I forgot about putting `restrict` in there; that should work.

Comment: @FreaknBigPanda: That is a 1-D array of scalars, and the compiler knows that different scalars in the array don't overlap.  It's fine to overwrite the same element; the problem in your initial code is that things may or may not overwrite the same elements in unpredictable (to the compiler) ways.

Comment: How do I put code in here wtf. Anyways I tried the restrict keyword. I declared the A_me2 as complex* restrict * A_me2, still with no luck.

Comment: I do not understanding why adding another dimension to the array changes how the complier interprets the situation. Here is the code with the restrict keywords that still does not compile:

Comment: int max = A->m;
 complex* restrict * restrict A_me2;
 complex fred; 
 
    for ( i = 0; i < max; i++ )
 {
  for ( j = 0; j < i-1; j++ )
  {
     A_me2[i][j] = fred; 
  A_me2[i][j] = fred;
  }
 }

Comment: @FreaknBigPanda: Does it not compiler or not run in parallel?

Comment: sorry. it compiles, but the loop does not parallelize for the same reason as mentioned above

Comment: @FreaknBigPanda: That's odd; `restrict` should take care of that issue.  Try adding `#pragma pipeloop(0)` before each `for` statement and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I added the pipeloop pragma and simplified the problem further (by removing the inner loop, just to isolate the issue) still with no luck. Maybe the solaris compiler straight up refuses to parallelize loops where the output of an assignment is a 2+ dimensional array?

Comment: int max = A->m;
 complex* restrict * restrict A_me2;
 complex fred;  
 
 #pragma pipeloop(0)
    for ( i = 0; i < max; i++ )
 {
     A_me2[i][4] = fred; 
  A_me2[i][4] = fred;
 }

Comment: @FreaknBigPanda: It could be that it doesn't like loops that use pointers.  Do you need to use auto-parallelization, or can you use OpenMP instead?

Comment: I have to use auto-parallelization

Comment: @FreaknBigPanda: You might need to post someplace like http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/community/index.html instead, since that site will be more likely to have people experienced with those particular compilers (and possibly the compiler developers).